# Show div if value selected jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function working in jQuery on Add form, but i need to fix the function to show the div on Edit form.

Example Add form:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#status').bind('change', function (e) { 
    if( $('#status').val() == 'Rejected') {
      $('#reason').show();
      $("#reason").css({ display: "inline-block" });
      $('#decision').hide();
    }
    else if( $('#status').val() == 'Accepted') {
      $('#reason').hide();
      $('#decision').show();
    }         
  });
});
```

Form:

```
<div class="status" style="display:inline-block;"> Status: 
<select name="status" id="status">
<option value="Accepted" selected="selected">Accepted</option>
<option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="reason" style="display:none;">&nbsp; Reason: <input type="text" name="reason" value="" placeholder="The reason..."></div>
<div id="decision" style="display:inline-block;">&nbsp; Decision:
<select name="decision">
<option value="Waiting" selected="selected">Waiting</option>
<option value="Send">Send</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VLQKw/)

Good, but when i open the Edit form and "Rejected" is selected the Reason is still in hide and Decision in show.

My question is, how can i do to get "Hide" Decision and "Show" Reason if is Rejected ?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just trigger the event to fire immediately with a `trigger('change')` like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#status').bind('change', function (e) { 
    if( $('#status').val() == 'Rejected') {
      $('#reason').show();
      $("#reason").css({ display: "inline-block" });
      $('#decision').hide();
    }
    else if( $('#status').val() == 'Accepted') {
      $('#reason').hide();
      $('#decision').show();
    }         
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VLQKw/1/

Comment: Perfect, missed the .trigger, Thx a lot.